# Need help moving specific PDF files in Google Cloud Storage to an SFTP, based on values located in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, sftp, power-automate, winscp

I have a use case where I need to copy PDF files stored in a Google Cloud Storage Bucket to an SFTP I have setup. The specific file names and locations within the bucket would be located in a Google BigQuery view.

My experience is limited, and I've been trying to figure this out using the tools I'm familiar with, but am struggling. These tools I feel comfortable with are:

- BigQuery
- Microsoft Flow
- SFTP
- WinSCP on a VirtualMachine using CMD prompts and .bat files

Any help with this would be grately appreciated, expecially if the tools listed above coule be used.

Comment: WinSCP can access GC bucket (via S3) and SFTP. So you can use it to download from the GC bucket to the local machine and then to upload it to SFTP.

Comment: Pentium10 answer is great!

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this with [Cloud Workflows](https://cloud.google.com/workflows),

Essentially you need to create a Workflow that

- runs the BigQuery select statement (example [here](https://medium.com/google-cloud/automate-the-execution-of-bigquery-queries-with-cloud-workflows-9fffe0557dbb))
- loop over the entries
- start a Cloud Build job that issue the relevant commands

  - download the file from GCS (similar to this [workflow](https://gist.github.com/pentium10/0399896fc79273bdc1be29d3d03d6744#file-workflow_cloudbuildcreatewait-yaml))
  - get the SFTP credentials from Secret Manager (similar to [this](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/samples/workflows-connector-secretmanager))
  - issue the upload file to SFTP commands

a good source for all these are parts from my two articles that you can find linked. Reach me out in private if you need help putting together.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you need to perform the following steps:

1. collect file names and paths by reading a bigquery table/view
2. for each file then download from GCS and upload on FTP server

Creating a script should be very simple and may be a great option for writing robust and testable procedure.

You can use Python (but also Java, Go, Bash...) for this as you can easily interact with Google BigQuery and Cloud Storage via API.

Then the FTP upload will follow based on the language you choose.

References:

1. Read data from bigquery: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bigquery-storage-python-pandas
2. Download data from GCS: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python